# How to create a string=$* without arguments $1 and $2

Tags: linux, bash, unix, arguments

I have a script that takes in several arguments.

I need everything but `$1` and `$2` in a string.

I have tried this:

```
message="$*"
words= $(grep -v "$2"|"$3" $message)
```

but it doesn't work, it gives me the error:

> ./backup: line 26: First: command not found

Comment: Can you give an example of arguments for script?

Comment: why don't you `shift 2`???

Comment: @oguzismail Maybe because they don't know about `shift`?

Comment: You get this "First: command not found" error because you are piping the output of `grep -v "$2"` into `"$3" $message` and `"$3"` is presumably `First`, and it can't find a command called `First`.

Comment: you want to type `words=$(...)`. (no space before the `=` ). But the other answers below are better style for shell scripting. Good luck.

Comment: By the way, your grep isn't going to work. The second argument of grep is files to search, not a string to search. Shift, or subranges fix your problem, eg `args=( "$@" )` `"${args[*]:2}"`

Answer (score 3):

Use `shift 2` to shift the arguments along (it drops the first *n* arguments).
If you need `"$1"` and `"$2"` for later, save them in variables first.

Note that in shell, assignments to variables cannot have whitespace either side of the `=`.

```
First=$1
Second=$2
shift 2
Message=$@
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subarray:

```
$ set -- arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4
$ str=${*:3}
$ echo "$str"
arg3 arg4
```

More often than not, it's good practice to preserve the arguments as separate elements, though, which you can do by using `$@` and assigning to a new array:

```
$ arr=("${@:3}")
$ declare -p arr
declare -a arr=([0]="arg3" [1]="arg4")
```

Notice that in `str=${*:3}`, quoting isn't necessary, but in `arr=("${@:3}")`, it is (or the arguments would be split on whitespace).

---

As for your error message: your command

```
words= $(grep -v "$2"|"$3" $message)
```

does the following:

- It sets a variable `words` to the empty string for the environment of the command (because there is a blank after `=`).
- It tries to set up a pipeline consisting of two commands, `grep -v "$2"` and `"$3" $message`. The first of these commands would just hang and wait for input; the second one tries to run the contents of `$3` as a command; presumably, based on your error message, `$3` contains `First`.
- If the pipeline would actually run, its output would be run as a command (again because of the blank to the right of `=`).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
[root@tsekmanrhel771 ~]# cat ./skip1st2.sh
#!/bin/bash

COUNT=0

for ARG in "$@"
do
    COUNT=$[COUNT + 1]

    if [ ${COUNT} -gt 2 ]; then
        RESULT="${RESULT} ${ARG}"
    fi
done

echo ${RESULT}

[root@tsekmanrhel771 ~]# ./skip1st2.sh first second third 4 5 6 7
third 4 5 6 7
```